# Choice free definition of category of descent data w.r.t a fibration?

Tags: ct.category-theory, descent, fibered-categories

Let $\mathsf C$ be a category and consider a pseudofunctor (non-strict 2-functor) $P:\mathsf C^{\text{op}}\to\mathsf{Cat}$. Given an arrow $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathsf C$, define the category of descent data of $f$ w.r.t $P$ to be the 2-limit of the image along $P$ of the Čech nerve of $f$.

Given a cloven fibration $\varphi:\mathsf D\to\mathsf C$ and an arrow $f$ in $\mathsf C$ we may also define the category of descent data of $f$ w.r.t $P$ by lifting the Čech nerve of $f$ to a diagram in $\mathsf{Cat}$ involving the fibers and base-change functors furnished by the cleavage.

The categories of descent data arising from a cloven fibration/pseudofunctor associated with each other via the Grothendieck construction seem to be isomorphic (not just equivalent).

1. Is there a choice-free definition of the category of descent data of an arrow w.r.t a fibration?
2. What is an explicit example of the advantage of fibrational descent as opposed to 2-functorial descent? I have read the criticisms of pseudofunctors vs fibrations in Bénabou's paper on foundations of naive category theory, but I cannot think of an explicit example which would justify moving from 2-functors to fibrations for purposes of descent theory. On the other hand, Grothendieck transitioned to fibrations in SGA1, so perhaps there are "concrete" motivations.

Comment: A minor advantage: presumably you need pullbacks in $\mathsf C$ to have the Čech nerves; you can do the fibrational version without this requirement.

Comment: The answer to (1) is clearly yes: use a choice-free construction to convert a Grothendieck fibration into a strict functor, then use the traditional choice-free definition of the descent category for a strict functor.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov How to convert a Grothendieck fibration into a strict functor without the axiom of choice (does this have to do with converting to an equivalent split fibration?)?

Comment: @Arrow: A choice-free construction is given here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction#the_left_adjoint

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე how?

Comment: You can always replace the Cech nerve by the sieve, so you don't need pullbacks in C anyway. I don't see how there could be a tangible advantage of one POV over the other, since they are equivalent. The reason fibrations are usually preferred is that they are easier to construct by hand than pseudofunctors.